# generating random numbers in verilog

Tags: random, verilog

I ran into this issue while writing a test bench for a project. I found how to use `$random` in verilog but for some reason it produces strange results for me. I have 2 16 bit regs called `A` and `B`, I tested it with random number between 0-10 every second output is a value which is the max value that you can have in 16 bits. I wonder if anyone else had had similar issue and can offer help. 
Thanks

```
reg[15:0]a;
reg[15:0]b;

 integer seed,i,j;
 initial begin 


   for (i=0; i<6; i=i+1)
    begin
      a=$random%10; 
      #100;
      b=$random%20;
    $display("A %d, B: %d",a,b);    
   end 
$finish;
```

Comment: `$random`, `$urandom`, `$srandom` and `$urandom_range()` are some of the system tasks for generating random numbers. `$urandom_range` generates random numbers in a given range. `$srandom` for seed specific random number generation.

Answer (score 13):

> output is a value which is the max value that you can have in 16 bits.

`$random` produces signed random numbers. Negative numbers will appear to be large numbers when you print it as unsigned numbers.

The code that you posted might appear something like below and this is not within the range from 0 to 10.

```
A     8, B: 65517
A 65527, B: 65527
A     7, B:    17
A 65535, B: 65522
A     1, B:     9
A     8, B:    17
```

As a solution, **use `$urandom` to generate unsigned random numbers** that you expect between 0 to 10 and 0 to 20.

Here is a modification from the code that you posted

```
module test;
   initial begin
      reg[15:0]a;
      reg [15:0] b;

      integer    seed,i,j;
      for (i=0; i<6; i=i+1)
        begin
           a=$urandom%10; 
           #100;
           b=$urandom%20;
           $display("A %d, B: %d",a,b);    
        end 
      $finish;
   end
endmodule
```

The code above might produce an output something like:

```
A     8, B:     0
A     3, B:    10
A     7, B:    11
A     6, B:     3
A     2, B:     7
A     1, B:    10
```

Which I guess is what you expect.

The code can be found and run [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Kda).